# Extract values from dictionaries in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm working on a quite simple thing : requesting something to a database, this one is returning me an [huge] dictionary. It's ok, I love dictionnaries. But i'm not a pro with this thing in Python.

My problem is that I want to convert this dictionary into a DataFrame. It's ok, I googled it and it works. But in my dictionary, I have others  dictionaries (yeah I know...).

**I want to take from those dictionaries (which are into my dataframe) the values of the "value" key**

Here's a sample and what I tried. Thank's in advance.

[[***res*** is my huge dictionary, the result from the query]]

res :

```
{'head': {'vars': ['id', 'marque', 'modele']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'id': {'type': 'literal', 'value': '1362'},
    'marque': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'PEUGEOT'},
    'modele': {'type': 'literal', 'value': '206'}},....
```

pd.DataFrame(res['results']['bindings'],columns=res['head']['vars']) :
[image]

**As you can see, there's another dictionary into my dataframe ! What I want is to take the values from the "value" key, in an efficient way** (indeed, I know how to do that with a big for statement but please, not in python).

I tried the things like `res['results']['bindings']['values']`, or `res['results']['bindings'].values() (or .values)`, and others things on the dataframe like `df.values()['value'] = df.values()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use an `applymap` and extract the value associated with the `value` key from every dictionary.

```
import operator

df = pd.DataFrame(res['results']['bindings'], columns=res['head']['vars']) 
df = df.applymap(operator.itemgetter('value'))
```

This operates under the assumption the each cell value is a dictionary.

---

It could be possible some of your dictionaries do not contain `value` as a key. In that case, a slight modification is required, using `dict.get`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.get('value', np.nan) \
                        if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
```

This will also handle the potential problems that arise when `x` is not a `dict`.

Comment: It works. And it's very efficient. Thank you ! :) Clément
Edit : thanks for your advice on the second part of your answer, it's usefull and yes, it can happen.

Comment: @ClementB Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) which perfectly add `NaN`s:

```
d = {'head': {'vars': ['id', 'marque', 'modele']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'id': {'type': 'literal', 'value': '1362'},
    'marque': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'PEUGEOT'},
    'modele': {'type': 'literal', 'value': '206'}},{'id': {'type': 'literal', 'value': '1362'},
    'marque': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'PEUGEOT'}}]}}
```

---

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(d['results']['bindings']).filter(like='value')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.value','')
print (df)
     id   marque modele
0  1362  PEUGEOT    206
1  1362  PEUGEOT    NaN
```